# What does akamaihd.net do?

Tags: twitter

I see twitter using scripts from akamaihd.net(using noscript). when i go to their website, it represents itself as a cloud company. does that mean twitter is using their cloud service to store tweets?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akamai_Technologies

Answer (score 20):

> does that mean twitter is using their cloud service to store tweets?

Maybe. [Akamai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akamai_Technologies) is an internet giant when it comes to content providers.

They just have a huge, world-wide network to deliver content to end users. Companies pay them money to host their content because they have a massive infrastructure to deliver content anywhere on the planet.

Wikipedia has [a nice graphic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Akamaiprocess.png) explaining the concept:
[image]